# MeteorJS : How do I check the data fetching from mongoDB on console client?

Tags: javascript, meteor

We have deploy the MeteorJS code on Ubuntu server. We haven't created any client to access this MeteorJS service. First we wanted to verify the service are running properly. Can any one suggest the steps for check the deployment is correct.

1. We install Meteor on Ubuntu : curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
2. MonogoDB - Already install for NodeJS application - Its Working!
3. Copy the Code Meteor Code to server using WinSCP
4. Set the MongoDB path for Code : export MONGO_URL=mongodb://ip:27017/userDB
5. Run Command to start the app: sudo nohup meteor --port 3001 --production &

Thanks.

Comment: You can test the connection between Meteor and Mongo by running `meteor shell` and then once it's loaded you can test the collections set up in your server side code: `YourCollection.find({});` to see if it returns any values. If you are looking for a framework or something else, check out `kadira` for Meteor monitoring/profiling.

Comment: Thanks Brett.  I am able to Connect to Database.  I have the the export command to set up Database connection , instead of IP address I have use localhost.  export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB.
Also I have change the command for to run app "meteor --port 3001"
It work for me.